# copy parts of a file from multiple sources over LAN using python

Tags: python, copy

Python seems to have functions for copying files (e.g. shutil.copy) and functions for copying directories.This also works with network paths.

Is there a way to copy only part of the file from multiple sources and merge them afterwards

Like a download manager downloads parts of a single file from multiple sources increasing  the overall download speed.

I want to achive the same over lan.

I have a file on more than two machines on my network.

How could i copy parts of file to a single destination from multiple sources ?

Can it be done with standard shutil libraries?

Comment: This technique achieves speed-ups over the internet, where point-to-point transfers fail to saturate the last-mile pipe, due to protocol inefficiencies and asymmetric upload/download rates available to consumer internet connections. Over a LAN, I'm not sure you'll experience much, if any, speed-up.

Comment: @MarceloCantos - It's handy if you were to be implementing a DC++ [http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/] style application

Comment: @ChristianWitts: What is the purpose of fetching a single file from multiple sources on a LAN?

Comment: @MarceloCantos - Lowering the total load on an individual machine. Try go to a hosted LAN with ~1500 people and say 10% all want the new Game of Thrones episode, it is lighter on individual machines and faster overall, to have everyone with a matching copy provide parts of it to all the requesting parties.

Comment: @MarceloCantos as christian witts said i am facing a similar kind of issue.

Comment: @MattH i want to copy some huge files ~1gb from one machine on a network to 40 -50 machines i want to do it in such a way that first it is copied to first set of 5 machines then from there to the rest of machines.it would be easier doing this way so that i dont put strain on a single machine.

Comment: @prattyy: Your use case may warrant distributing the files across the LAN, but I still don't see why that requires fetching the files in chunks. If each client fetches the entire file from a single randomly select source, the typical load on sources will be roughly the same as it would be with chunked fetching. At least that will be the case in a high-traffic situation; in low-traffic, no one cares if the load distribution is spiky. Morever, this can be done in a few lines of code with shutil (assuming everyone can mount everyone else's shares) or urllib2 (assuming everyone runs a web server).

Answer (score 0):

- Stat the file to find the size
- Divvy up the the start:end points that each reader will handle
- Open your write file in binary mode
- Open your readers in binary mode
- Handle the merging/collating of data when writing it out

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a free open source peer-to-peer library.

Peer-to-peer file transfers are effective for the problem you are describing: *to copy some huge files ~1gb from one machine on a network to 40 -50 machines*

E.g. http://code.google.com/p/python-libtorrent/

Or use a client implementation.